# override << operator of a composition object gives error c++

Tags: c++, overriding, composition

I'm still fairly new to c++ and am having some trouble.
When i try to do `cout << v.getR();` everything works fine, but when I want to override the << operator so I can print out all the information of the object with one line it gives an error that says:
`valjak.cpp|4|error: passing 'const Valjak' as 'this' argument of 'double Valjak::getR()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|`
I declared the override in the .hpp as so (pretty much copy paste from my book):

`friend ostream & operator << (ostream&, const Valjak &);`

and in the .cpp defined it as so:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Valjak &v) {
out << "Poluprecnik:\t" << v.getR() << "\nVisina:\t\t" << v.getH() << "\nPovrsina:\t\t"
    << v.getP() << "\nZapremina:\t\t" << v.getV() << endl;
return out;
}
```

What an I doing wrong here?? I've never overridden an operator for a composition object before so any pointers on how to avoid errors like this in the future are very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try reading the documentation here and figure out where are you going wrong : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

Comment: No use. I now know it's called overloading :D but I know how to do it for regular classes. Why is it different for compositions?

Comment: I wish people people didn't downvote for no reason...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was caused by me not putting `const` at the get methods and passing the object reference as `const`. Doing that resolved the problem.